# VTK how to smooth a line

Tags: c++, tcl, vtk

I need to smooth a line which seems like [vtkContourWidget](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.10/html/classvtkContourWidget.html) shows. but the line is not closed on which there is one start point and one end point.

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but your question is currently a bit unclear. Are you trying to use vtkContourWidget? What programming language (or languages) are you using? What data have you got to define the line? What is not working for what you have tried? What *have* you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vtkParametricSpline to smooth the data, then a vtkParametricFunctionSource to get back a discrete point representation. Both are shown here:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/ParametricSpline